# How to change multiple labels one at a time? - Swift

Tags: swift

I've got 5 labels and for each label im assigning a random value from an array when a button is clicked. Im wanting the first label to be changed then the second and then the third etc... but cannot seem to get it working. I've tried a loop and a timer to try and make the effect

Comment: Some code would go a long way in helping people help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, you have to create an array of labels or a collection of labels.

```
func assignLabel(){
        if yourArray.count > labelsArrays.count {
            yourArray.removeFirst()
        }
        for i in 0..<yourArray.count {
            labelsArrays[i].text = yourArray[i]
        }
    }
```